# How to make PrimeFace's Editor Right To Left

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to make the *PrimeFaces's Editor* component, **right to left**?
It seems not to support dir and style attributes... :(

Answer (score 1):

in my experience controls in jsf framework like prime/open/etc.. don't support RTL using html @dir,
usually the interfaces of these controls are built using Javascript, so probably you should work at that level.
Can I suggest you to consider two other alternatives to jsf controls in this case?:

1. Using a javascript html editor (like elrte, maybe is easier to customize and it has also Arabic translation). http://elrte.org/
2. Using the Flex html editor (is Flash, if you can, and Flex support RTL for all controls)

F.

Answer (score 1):

Just bumped into this thread by accident,

anyway I remember that i did the RTL with jquery  like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("j_idt33:inputtextlist").contents().find('html').attr('dir', 'rtl');                          
});
```

had to find the id with firebug , inputtextlist was the id i gave to the editor , and ypu can always use a smarter jquery selector (with suffix match)